# Fortran `exit` can't pass R package cran check

Tags: r, fortran, r-package

I am using Fortran in my package. There are lots of `exit`(equivalent break in R) in Fortran script.

For example:

```
FUNCTION arth_d(first,increment,n)
  REAL(DP), INTENT(IN) :: first,increment
  INTEGER(I4), INTENT(IN) :: n
  REAL(DP), DIMENSION(n) :: arth_d
  INTEGER(I4) :: k,k2
  REAL(DP) :: temp
  if (n > 0) arth_d(1)=first
  if (n <= NPAR_ARTH) then
     do k=2,n
        arth_d(k)=arth_d(k-1)+increment
     end do
  else
     do k=2,NPAR2_ARTH
        arth_d(k)=arth_d(k-1)+increment
     end do
     temp=increment*NPAR2_ARTH
     k=NPAR2_ARTH
     do
        if (k >= n) exit
        k2=k+k
        arth_d(k+1:min(k2,n))=temp+arth_d(1:min(k,n-k))
        temp=temp+temp
        k=k2
     end do
  end if
END FUNCTION arth_d
```

When check the package, I got:

```
checking compiled code ... WARNING
  File 'SMI/libs/i386/SMI.dll':
    Found 'exit', possibly from 'exit' (C), 'stop' (Fortran)
      Object: 'mo_sort.o'
  File 'SMI/libs/x64/SMI.dll':
    Found 'exit', possibly from 'exit' (C), 'stop' (Fortran)
      Object: 'mo_sort.o'

  Compiled code should not call entry points which might terminate R nor
  write to stdout/stderr instead of to the console, nor use Fortran I/O
  nor system RNGs.
```

I used `C` to register `Fortran` external functions. R might regard `exit` from `C` and lead to the warning.

Any solution?

Comment: Are you *really* sure cran is complaining about *this* subroutine? EXIT is a problem in C while the problematic statemnt in Fortran is STOP.  Look for that one. Do not show "for example" show the actual small pice of code that does not pass.